# Windows server 2008 R2, no permission on file

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

My Windows Server 2008 has a program on a shared folder. A remote user antivirus (trend micro) considered this program a virus and tried to remove/quarantine it. However, it didn't possess the required authorization, and now nobody -- **not even me the administrator** -- can access or administer this file.  Now the owner is **"..."**.

For example:

```
dir  /Q /P
19/10/2016  15:19  1.941.504   ...   MG_Menu.exe

takeown.exe  /a /f  .\MG_Menu.exe
ERROR: Access denied.
```

What does this mean?

How can I acquire again the ownership?

Comment: Follow the instructions here and see if they work: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: No result. I have no permissions...

Answer (score 0):

Always, for any file, the `NT_Authority\System` will be able to modify its permissions. To run `icacls` or `takeown` as the System:

1. Download the PsExec tool from Microsoft's Website, [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). Open a normal Administrator Command Prompt (Win+X then Command Prompt (Admin)).
2. In it, run `psexec –i –s CMD`. If prompted with password, enter. If asked for the SYSTEM password, it should be nothing so just press enter. This should allow you to run the computer as NT_Authority\System.
3. Give yourself full control to the file by running:

   `icacls MG_Menu.exe /grant domainname\Administrator:(F,WDAC)`
4. Make yourself the owner of the file by running:

   `icacls MG_Menu.exe /setowner domainname\Administrator`

   Or to make it owned by the System Authority (unless your `whoami` differs):

   `takeown.exe /a /f .\MG_Menu.exe`